# handleRequest() with PATCH method

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

To avoid using multiple `FormType` files, I'm submitting a form with `PATCH` method.
But symfony `handleRequest()` doesn't submit because there is a difference in method between the form config and the request.

First, setting form method in controller (to be able to submit)

```
$form=$this->createForm(UtilisateurType::class, $utilisateur, array(
    'action'=>$this->generateUrl('security_edit_user', array('id'=>$utilisateur->getId())),
    'method'=>'POST',
));
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Then overwritting form method in twig when submitted

```
<form action="{{ form.vars.action }}" method="{{ form.vars.method }}" name="{{ form.vars.name }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- editor-fold -->
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
    <!-- editor-fold -->
</form>
```

The problem lie in `handleRequest()` function (`vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php`).
The function will compare the form method and the request method, and prevent submit if they're different.

```
$method = $form->getConfig()->getMethod();
if ($method !== $request->getMethod()) {
    return;
}
```

Thus, I would like to know the reason behind this condition. Why does Symfony check if the methods are the same for the form and the request.

Then, is it possible to correct/bypass this? How would you recommand to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you want to use REST-ish approach, you would want to turn away from forms as much as possible (in traditional terms). As you well noticed, traditional forms only support `POST` and `GET` methods so `PATCH` will not work.

Alternately, what you can do is

- on client side, maintain `JSON` representation of your domain object
- implement two-way binding (optional)
- do not submit form but rather fire up a new `PATCH` HTTP request to your server containing `JSON` of new state

Your server side should not `handleRequest` anymore, but instead `$form->submit($data)`. The `$data` should be deserialized `JSON` from request body (if any). If you feel super lazy, there is a bundle for doing just that: [qandidate-labs/symfony-json-request-transformer](https://github.com/qandidate-labs/symfony-json-request-transformer) :)

With this, you circumvent form limitation of `POST`/`GET`, but you still retain validation logic.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I see... Guess it can't be helped, I will split my `FormType` into a few files. I'm not familliar with things like REST. Thanks for the reply.